# How to change paper-action-dialog programmaticaly

Tags: polymer

I would like to know if it is possible to create/change content of this paper-action-dialog programmaticaly? 
(heading, content and also buttons and their actions)

```
<paper-action-dialog heading="Dialog Title">
  <p>Some content</p>
  <paper-button dismissive>More Info</paper-button>
  <paper-button affirmative>Decline</paper-button>
  <paper-button affirmative>Accept</paper-button>
</paper-action-dialog>
```

Thanks a lot for any suggestions or examples.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the `paper-action-dialog` element in a `template` element and utilize Polymer expression to update the content programmatically.

```
<template is='auto-binding' id='dialogTemp'>
  <paper-action-dialog heading="{{ diaLogTitle }}">
    <p>{{ diaLogContent }}</p>
    <paper-button dismissive>More Info</paper-button>
    <paper-button affirmative>Decline</paper-button>
    <paper-button affirmative>Accept</paper-button>
  </paper-action-dialog>
<template>

<script>
var dialogTemp = document.getElementById('dialogTemp');

dialogTemp.dialogTitle = "Dialog Title";
dialogTemp.dialogContent = "Dialog Content";
</script>
```

More about data-binding and template at:
https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding.html

Comment: Thanks Adi. All what did you write is clear for me.
To be more specific I am trying to understand this polymer-meteor example: https://github.com/Differential/polymer-demo/blob/master/client%2FglobalUI.coffee#L1-L47

It looks that passing opts I can define how dialog will be.

Comment: I am sorry pbelo I have limited knowledge in both Meteor and CoffeeScript.

Comment: That's OK, I appreciate your help.